# Manipulating/Printing a user inputted array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am inputting a array of numbers using the scanner class. I need to print these numbers, 5 per line. 
Example:

How big is the Array: 20

Enter 20 whole numbers: 
92 71 20 13 18 65 21 72 97 100 73 22 87 19 99 100 64 29 45 88

**The array contains:

92 71 20 13 18

65 21 72 97 100

73 22 87 19 99

100 64 29 45 88
**

Im having trouble getting the loop and variables correct.

This is my method for reading the input:

```
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    //prompt to enter size of Array 
        System.out.print("How big is the Array: ");
        n = keyboard.nextInt();
        numbers = new int[n];

    //prompt to enter numbers in Array
        System.out.println("\nEnter " +n + " whole numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {    
                numbers [i]=  keyboard.nextInt();
            }
```

This is my code that Im having trouble with

```
    for (int i= 0 ; i < 5; i++)
    {
         for (int l = 0 ; l < 5; l++)
         System.out.print (numbers [l]+ " ");
         System.out.println();
  }
```

this is not giving me the inputted numbers, it is just giving me 1-5 line after line.

I need help getting the inputted array into a variable and then forming a loop to manipulate it.

Comment: "Im having trouble getting the loop and variables correct" what problems are you facing exactly? Are you getting error/exception/incorrect values?

Comment: I really cannot even figure out how to get the inputted data into the loop.                              
        this is my code                                                                                 
 for (int i= 0 ; i < 5; i++)
        {
             for (int l = 0 ; l < 5; l++)
             System.out.print (numbers [l]+ " ");
             System.out.println();
        }
            
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(i % 5 == 0) System.out.println();
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
    }
```

Comment: amazing! Thank you Zlakad. Can you explain the if statement to me? I think i understand everything else.

Comment: If statement means: is the number i divisible by 5